# Can I use Homebrew to install MySQL 5.6.26?

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I was asked to install mysql 5.6.26 using Homebrew.

I searched for some time and found [Homebrew-versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions). There is a mysql56 formulae, but it's 5.6.29.

Is there a way to install mysql 5.6.26 with Homebrew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to dig through Homebrew history and install specific old version of brew formulae, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/1032396

However, the earliest version of MySQL in the history is 5.6.27:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/commits/master/mysql56.rb

So, no, you cannot install 5.6.26 using Homebrew.